# why does an ARM template create a separate app service plan?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'd like to understand why an entire *app service plan* was created, and not just an azure function along with app insights:

[image]

**Is it not possible to create an Azure Function App without forcing the creation of an app service plan?**

[image]

**How do you create an Azure Function using an ARM template, without creating the App Service Plan component?**

Here's my full template:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "accountType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "appName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "storageAccessTier": "Hot",
        "storageKind": "StorageV2",
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
        "functionAppName": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
        "storageAccountid": "[concat(resourceGroup().id,'/providers/','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2018-07-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "accessTier": "[variables('storageAccessTier')]",
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "[variables('supportsHttpsTrafficOnly')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [],
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('accountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "[variables('storageKind')]"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "[toLower(variables('functionAppName'))]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                            "value": "6.5.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference(resourceId('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "tags": {
                "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]": "Resource"
            },
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may miss the `serverFarmId` in your template. Try the template below, it will not create a separate app service plan, in my sample, it attaches the Function App to the existing app service plan `joyplan` and storage account `joystoragev1`, creates app insight `joytestfuninsight` and attaches to it.

Sample:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "storageName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "dotnet"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('b83c1ed3-c5b6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f','joywebapp','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                            "value": "8.11.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/joytestfuninsight', '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "alwaysOn": true
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "microsoft.insights/components/joytestfuninsight"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "name": "joytestfuninsight",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My test parameters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "value": "joytestfun"
        },
        "storageName": {
            "value": "joystoragev1"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "value": "joyplan"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "Central US"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "value": "joywebapp"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

If you want to create a Function App with a consumption plan, you could refer to the template below.

Sample:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "storageName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "kind": "functionapp",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "Central US",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "dotnet"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('b83c1ed3-xxxxxxxxxxx-2b83a074c23f','joywebapp','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('b83c1ed3-xxxxxxxxxxx-2b83a074c23f','joywebapp','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
                            "value": "[concat(toLower(parameters('name')), 'b32d')]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
                            "value": "8.11.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/joytest11insight', '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "reserved": false
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "microsoft.insights/components/joytest11insight"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "name": "joytest11insight",
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My test parameters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "value": "joytest11"
        },
        "storageName": {
            "value": "joystoragev1"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "central us"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "value": "b83c1ed3-xxxxxxxxxxx-2b83a074c23f"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: again, there's no need at all for an app service plan. i'm not sure why it's only enforced through ARM template, and not when you deploying from vs

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' The function must have a service plan or consumption plan, you could check your function created from vs in the portal, does it have a consumption plan?

Comment: i suppose the question is, how do you get it to do a consumption plan

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' If you want to create a Function App with a consumption plan, you could see my update.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function requires app service plan to operate, so you cant really create Azure Function without one.

You can attach new Azure Function to already existing App Service plan, thats about it.

Comment: im not sure if that's true. if you create an azure function in visual studio and right click --> deploy , it will create that function without having to create a service plan for it

Comment: hm, weird, it appears it definitely doesnt create app service plan on consumption anymore... mhm, never mind, it just doesnt appear instantly, its there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale